# How to resize a table / ListObject in Excel, with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How to remove empty rows and columns from a table using `ListObject.Resize` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The initial table row must remain the same, and the resulting range must overlap

[image]

If the UsedRange of the table is larger than the UsedRange of the sheet:

- Empty columns on the left and right will be removed (if the table doesn't have headers)
- Empty rows will be removed only from the bottom

If the UsedRange of the table is smaller than the UsedRange of the sheet the table will be expanded to include:

- all columns outside of the table UsedRange (left and right)
- all rows bellow the table UsedRange

---

Sheet 1 contains one sample table - VBA code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub resizeTables()

    resizeTableUsedRangeV1 ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)

End Sub
```

---

Module 1:

- version 1 - always resize the table
- version 2 - resize the table only if table UsedRange is different than sheet UsedRange

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub resizeTableUsedRangeV1(ByRef tbl As ListObject)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ur As Range, maxCell As Range
    Dim fr As Long, lr As Long         'first and last row on worksheet (used range)
    Dim fc As Long, lc As Long         'first and last column on worksheet (used range)

    If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = tbl.Parent
        Set ur = ws.UsedRange
        Set maxCell = GetMaxCell(ur)
        fr = ur.Row
        fc = ur.Column
        lr = maxCell.Row
        lc = maxCell.Column
        tbl.Resize ws.Range(ws.Cells(tbl.DataBodyRange.Row, fc), ws.Cells(lr, lc))
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub resizeTableUsedRangeV2(ByRef tbl As ListObject)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ur As Range, tblRng As Range, maxCell As Range
    Dim fr As Long, lr As Long         'first and last row on worksheet (used range)
    Dim fc As Long, lc As Long         'first and last column on worksheet (used range)
    Dim frTbl As Long, fcTbl As Long   'first row and column in table (used range)
    Dim lrTbl As Long, lcTbl As Long   'last row and column in table (used range)

    If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = tbl.Parent
        Set ur = ws.UsedRange
        Set tblRng = tbl.DataBodyRange

        Set maxCell = GetMaxCell(ur)

        fr = ur.Row
        fc = ur.Column
        lr = maxCell.Row
        lc = maxCell.Column

        frTbl = tblRng.Row
        fcTbl = tblRng.Column
        lrTbl = frTbl + tblRng.Rows.Count - 1
        lcTbl = fcTbl + tblRng.Columns.Count - 1

        If fc <> fcTbl Or lr <> lrTbl Or lc <> lcTbl Then
            'first row of a table can not change
            tbl.Resize ws.Range(ws.Cells(frTbl, fc), ws.Cells(lr, lc))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function GetMaxCell(Optional ByRef rng As Range = Nothing) As Range
    'It returns the last cell of range with data, or A1 if Worksheet is empty
    Const NONEMPTY As String = "*"

    Dim lRow As Range, lCol As Range

    If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = Application.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
        Set GetMaxCell = rng.Parent.Cells(1, 1)
    Else
        With rng
            Set lRow = .Cells.Find(What:=NONEMPTY, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                   After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                   searchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                   searchOrder:=xlByRows)
            Set lCol = .Cells.Find(What:=NONEMPTY, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                   After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                   searchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                   searchOrder:=xlByColumns)
            Set GetMaxCell = .Parent.Cells(lRow.Row, lCol.Column)
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple approach. Where "Table1" is the table name you would like to resize, "A1" is the first cell in your table,
(0, 0) is the starting point for resizing, and (2, 3) represents the new size of the table. In this case 2 rows and 3 columns from the starting point.

```
Sub ResizeMacro()
    
    With Sheet1
        .ListObjects("Table1").Resize .Range("A1").Offset(0, 0).Resize(2, 3)
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: After much searching, this is the by far the simplest solution for adding rows to the bottom of a table in VBA. Formulas are automatically propagated to the new rows. Unfortunately, if you use it to reduce the size of the table, all the data, formulas and formatting are left on the worksheet but outside the table. I have some other thoughts but I will post them elsewhere and add another comment with a link.